# GitHub Action Runner: deploy 2 environments (dev and prod) on a same server

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a webserver and I want to deploy 2 environment: dev and prod on it. Don't understand how GitHub Actions works.

I have succeeded to deploy one environment (prod) but not both. I have 2 branches: one for the dev (it called "dev") and one for the prod (it called "main").

How do I suppose to do? Do I have to make a YAML file for each environment on their respective branches or do I have to write all deployments on the same file? How can I say for an environment to deploy a specific branch of my repository? On my webserver, do I have to deploy 2 services runner application or just 1 for both environment? How can I suppose to have both branches on _work directory?

This is my main.yaml file (runner) for only prod environment (it works):

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]
    
    environment:
      name: myprod-environment
      url: https://www.mywebsite.com

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate --strict

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

I've tried to write a dev.yml on .github/workflows directory but I can't say for my github action runner service to deploy this environnment instead of main.yml.

I've also tried to add a new section on jobs into main.yml (like "build") but for dev deployment but even if I change the branch and I force the environnment to use a branch, it doesn't deploy both of jobs on _work directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a [job for matrices](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#using-a-matrix-strategy)

> Use `jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix` to define a matrix of different job configurations.
> Within your matrix, define one or more variables followed by an array of values

But using non-primitive values in the matrix is not supported.
However, you can achieve the same goal using job outputs and a separate job for each environment.

That means using a single YAML file that handles both environments:

```yaml
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux]

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Print current branch
      run: echo "Current branch: ${{ github.ref }}"

    - name: Set deploy path and environment based on branch
      run: |
        if [ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/heads/main" ]; then
          echo "DEPLOY_PATH=/var/www/mywebsite/prod" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "ENV_NAME=myprod-environment" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "ENV_URL=https://www.mywebsite.com" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        elif [ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/heads/dev" ]; then
          echo "DEPLOY_PATH=/var/www/mywebsite/dev" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "ENV_NAME=mydev-environment" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "ENV_URL=https://dev.mywebsite.com" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

    - name: Configure environment
      echo "Environment:" ${{ env.ENV_NAME }}

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate --strict

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress

    - name: Deploy code to server
      run: |
        sudo chown -R your-user:your-group .
        sudo rsync -av --delete --exclude '.git' . ${{ env.DEPLOY_PATH }}
```

That creates a single build job. The "`Set deploy path and environment based on branch`" step sets the `DEPLOY_PATH`, `ENV_NAME`, and `ENV_URL` environment variables based on the current branch.

That means you only need a single self-hosted runner on your web server.
When the workflow runs, it will create separate jobs for each environment and deploy the respective branches based on the configuration.

But that also supposes your server (Apache?, NGiNX?, ...) needs to be configured to serve *both* environments correctly, typically with:

- two folders (`/var/www/mywebsite/prod`, `/var/www/mywebsite/dev`)
- two virtual hosts, one for each folder

That is why the workflow has a `DEPLOY_PATH` env variable, and a step to copy the files to the appropriate directory on your server after the "`Install dependencies`" step.
The `DEPLOY_PATH` variable is then used in the "`Deploy code to server`" step.

Don't forget to replace `your-user` and `your-group` in the "`Deploy code to server`" step with the appropriate user and group for your server.

Comment: On line 16, GitHub editor says (for env): "Matrix options must only contain primitive values"

Comment: @raymater OK, I have edited the answer to propose an alternative option *not* based on matrices (which are too limited for what I had in mind).

Comment: Right. But now how can I suppose to say to my runner service deployed to attach it with 2 environments? My current service is attached only on production environnment.

Comment: The runner will be able to handle both environments automatically based on the branch that triggers the workflow. The `build-prod` and `build-dev` jobs in the workflow have their own environment configurations, and they will run on the self-hosted runner depending on which branch was pushed. As long as your self-hosted runner is registered with the repository that contains the workflow, it will automatically run the appropriate job for each environment when a push event occurs on either the `main` or `dev` branch.

Comment: It doesn't work. My dev environment is not deployed : job was skipped. I suppose to have to reconfigure my service, but how?

Comment: @raymater Can you tell me more about your runner and service?

Comment: @raymater I have edited the workflow and removed the `on` trigger at the top of the workflow and added an `if` condition for the `actions/checkout@v3` step in each job. This way, each job will run on every push event, but the checkout step will only run for the corresponding branch. Let me know if that is working better that way

Comment: Error on GitHub editor : "Missing required root key on"

Comment: @raymater Right, `on` is mandatory: I have restored it in the workflow.

Comment: It works but I see that the directory for the dev env is the same as prod env. So how can I distinguish files from both branches to create my new vhost on Apache2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253640/discussion-between-vonc-and-raymater).